# Where is the air hose from the manifold located on a 2006 jeep liberty?

Tags: jeep, hvac, climate-control, liberty

I have no heat at idle in my jeep liberty and I'm hoping to just repair as a temp fix.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Hmmm, it's not clear to me what you mean by "air hose from the manifold". Hot air doesn't reach the cabin from the engine directly, but rather through coolant which is used to help keep the engine cool. It seems that the real issue you're looking to solve is lack of heating rather than knowing where the "air hose" is located. Can you confirm this is the case?

Comment: Are you asking about where the vacuum line comes from off of the intake manifold to operate the HVAC blend doors and such? Maybe you'd like to describe to us exactly what your issues are so we can help you better? Like Zaid said, welcome to the site! We are here to help, no doubt.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 the blend doors etc... are all electronically actuated on that year. To the OP, what's the engine size?

Comment: Have you checked your coolant level?

Comment: @Ben - Good to know. I know most modern vehicles are actuated as suggested, I was just trying to ask a clarifying question of the OP to see if that was their reasoning behind their question.